# Tool for draining/crushing isobutane fuel canister

Tags: canister-stoves, fuel

I have seen a tool that helps drain the last of the fuel out of your isobutane fuel canister, and then pierce it to make it easy to crush. It's a simple little gadget that looks like a can opener. 
What is this tool called and/or where can I buy it online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This (Jetboil Crunchit Recycling Tool)](http://www.rei.com/product/813638/jetboil-crunchit-recycling-tool) was found by googling "[crush isobutane fuel can](https://www.google.com/search?q=crush%20isobutane%20fuel%20can)" and reading this second result (right below the outoors.SE question) for the link.

Comment: Thanks. Should the link ever become invalid, the answer to the question is Jetboil Crunchit Recycling Tool

Comment: Good point - added it in

Answer (score 3):

Cheaper and easier solution.

Attach your stove thingy (In my case, a pocket rocket).  Open all the way and invert the can (away from flame sources obviously).

Use a cheap and old fashioned [church key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churchkey) to puncture the side.

Total cost, approx. $0.50.